# read/write speed of couchbase cluster

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I use nodejs to access couchbase cluster.
Just wonder if the read/write speed of couchbase is fast enough that I can regard couchbase cluster as in-memory array/list?
As I know the communication way of couchbase cluster is socket.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In absolute terms, no. You can't compare the complex interactions of an secondary process communicating via sockets with many users to the performance of a local array. There are too many moving parts. If I was looking to squeeze the most out of a local process, I wouldn't even consider it.

The real question is whether the performance difference between the two are important, and whether the additional benefits of running Couchbase are worth it.

While Couchbase maintains a memchache compatible interface, you should ask yourself if a commercial product is better than the original memchache. But, more important, is the complexity of running and maintaining multiple services worth it?

You need to test both in your environment to see if either solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes data is served out of RAM much like memcached, except unlike memcached can be distributed and horizontally scaled (along with persisted). So it is quite fast. The connection to Couchbase from your app server is a persistent (always connected) tcp binary socket connection, so that's very fast as well.